# Auto Increment vs Unique key difference When you have them both in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What's the use of Auto increment primary key in a table, If I'm not using it anywhere when querying.

For e.g. I've a form where user registers himself userid/passwd and etc and a table populates like below.

```
user table

id int auto increment primary key
userid unique key 
passwd varchar
etc
etc
```

Whenever I check for login user or any other queries I always user `select * from tbname where userid = ?`
there I've an unique index so what's the use of having primary index on id column?

Is there will be any speed difference as well?

Edit: My userid is actually a username choose my user who registers.

I've tagged this question under mysql and sql server because it could belong to both.

Comment: Not much value in this case (assuming userid is a simple integer numeric value), most database developers would set their userid to be the autoincrement column and drop the id column.... because then they don't need to allocate the unique userid in code

Comment: if a column is auto increment value is incremented by 1 when new record is inserted. so we have no need to decide what will be the next value of that column and this concept is applied to the primary key which is unique.

Answer (score 5):

Auto-increment and keys (primary or unique) are two different things.

The difference between the key types are:

Primary Key:

- Only one in each table
- No nulls are allowed
- Primary Key is a unique key identifier

Unique Key:

- There can be many unique keys in a table
- Nulls are allowed

Auto-increment is a different thing all together.

When you select auto-increment in a column, you don't provide a value when inserting a record. The database will keep track of the last incremented ID inserted, and the next insert will use the value after (incremented by the amount you specify, most commonly 1)

Comment: Agree but it's necessary to have primary key on id because in every query I'm using userid(username) while querying in where clause.

Comment: 4 upvotes, actually I know the theory difference, I'm not able to know what's the use of having them both in one table where I'm using uniquekey(userid) every time in where clause and primary key(id)(autoincrment) isn't getting used.

Comment: Use it where it fits the type. Like you say, have the primary key on the literal primary key (userid in your case). If you have a key which is unique, give it a unique index.

Answer (score 2):

You question is more about database-design than about specific DBMS. You're confused, because of mixing **surrogate key** and **natural key**, it seems.

**Surrogate key**

Is good because it has no real meaning - it's needed only for row identifying. It is a most common design - because your data set may have no other identifying conditions or they are unreliable. Your `id` seems to be that surrogate key.

**Natural key**

In some particular cases, table may have *natural key* - i.e. some attribute or set of attributes that can serve same purpose as surrogate key - i.e. *identify a row in table* . If that is so, then you may think about making natural key as primary key in table.

**What is better?**

In case if your `userid` column has some generation algorithm, it can not be auto-increment, obviously, and it will have sense of *natural* key. If you are sure that this key will *always* be unique - then your `id` column is redundant - there's no sense in maintaining column, the only role of which (i.e. row identifying) is already maintained by another column. And there's nothing bad in the fact, that your primary key column will not be auto-increment (here, again , I assume that `userid` has some generation algorithm).

Think about your `id` as about some convention - because it's **you** who decide - either you need to have special row-identifying column or you don't. However, your `id` is even more redundant if your `userid` has no special generation algorithm. In that case you may just drop `id` and define `userid` as auto-increment. As conclusion - keep in mind

> Conventions are good if they are helpful

Comment: userid is username chose by user who registers on website, so no algo for it.

Comment: But then how are you maintaining your uniqueness? Just check before insert? Seems to be not a very good idea. But from design level - it's even more _natural key_ then (because it holds some meaningful information at least)

Comment: as my userid has unique key so I'm making sure unique usernames are inserted. You're saying it's good to have id(surrogate key)(primary keyIndex) along with userid(username)(natural key) unique key index knowing I'll be always using userid in where clause.

Comment: I'm saying that if you have good natural key column - then there's no need in such convention as `id`

Comment: @Alam Do yeah need to figure out what would make it good natural key now!

Answer (score 1):

Surrogate primary keys are usually preferred by developers because they are not affected by little life changes. For example, one day you might decide that you want to let your users change their ids and then you have a non-zero chance to mess things up if you have other tables referencing this one by userid. With a surrogate key there is zero chance that it will ever need to change in any way. It's just safer to use.

But I also want to mention that besides primary, unique, auto-increment, natural, and surrogate keys there is also a matter of clustered vs non-clustered index. Clustered index is the one that is used to physically store the table rows. So it provides the fastest access. And it's not obvious to many beginners that primary key does **not** have to be your clustered index. If you know that 90% of the time you are going to use userid in your queries and want to leverage that, but cannot guarantee that userid will never be null (or changed) then make the surrogate id your primary non-clustered key and make userid your natural unique clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

There's no use in this case. In normal table design, you would use auto increment on user_id, to generate a unique primary key. If you throw away your auto increment ID column, you save yourself some index space. You should set user_id to primary to avoid nulls.

Auto increment is an automated generation of a row id, which does not repeat. It's a useful way to generate a unique user id. However, having it provides no uniqueness guarantee, as you can go back and edit a value, if there is no unique restriction